# 18.04: kernel panic - not syncing: attempting to kill init! exit code-0x00000100

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I have dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu.

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Release: 18.04
- Codename: bionic

All of a sudden my ubuntu terminal crashed and won't start, so I did a system reboot.
But now on system reboot I am getting end kernel panic- not syncing:attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000100.

[image]

Please help how can I start my system without losing any data.

Comment: Yeah, @gman is on the spot here. If the exact panic messages is: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 And the call trace contains: entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+... Then the issue is that root file system is missing one or more of mount points: `sys` `proc` `dev` `run` `tmp`. If the symptoms are not **EXACTLY** the same as described, then go with what @heynnema wrote, as his answer allows to diagnose further a similar issue - as the cause can be in `initrd`, or in `rootfs`, or a hardware problem on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem:

```
[    4.764737] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[    4.776126] XFS (xvda1): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[    4.893714] XFS (xvda1): Ending clean mount
[    5.004157] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[    5.004157] 
[    5.006315] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.118-2
[    5.007370] Call Trace:
[    5.008428]  dump_stack+0x66/0x90
[    5.009433]  panic+0xe7/0x24a
[    5.010396]  do_exit.cold.22+0x6b/0x6f
[    5.011340]  ? handle_mm_fault+0xd6/0x200
[    5.012250]  do_group_exit+0x3a/0xa0
[    5.013152]  __x64_sys_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    5.014035]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
[    5.014975]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[    5.015880] RIP: 0033:0x7f6ea102e9d6
[    5.016828] Code: 00 4c 8b 0d bc 44 0f 00 eb 19 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 89 d7 89 f0 0f 05 48 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 22 f4 89 d7 44 89 c0 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 76 e2 f7 d8 64 41 89 01 eb da 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00
[    5.019793] RSP: 002b:00007ffe7a11ef98 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[    5.020847] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005607492f0704 RCX: 00007f6ea102e9d6
[    5.021883] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000001
[    5.022945] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff80
[    5.023988] R10: 0000000000000006 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 00007ffe7a11f328
[    5.025046] R13: 00007ffe7a11f320 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[    5.026115] Kernel Offset: disabled
```

Finally appeared that the directories:
sys proc dev run tmp
ware missing from the root file system ..

BR
LAZA

Comment: So what is the answer? Can you tell the OP how to fix it? This is just a "Yeah, I've got that problem too " comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your file system, and/or rebuild your initrd.img file. Your BIOS is also antique, but that's not your current problem.

**FSCK:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**INITRD.IMG** (use only if fsck didn't fix your problem)

- from the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, then Recovery Mode, then Root access
- at the # prompt

  - `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

**BIOS:** (upgrade only after the system is stable, and after you've done backups)

- you have BIOS 1.5.0
- BIOS 1.19.3 can be had at https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-e5470-laptop/drivers