# End Kernel Panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, 22.04, init

So, after my laptop froze when rebooting on a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04 (dual boot with W11), every time I need to boot I end up with this message (cannot attach picture of the output for clarity due to low reputation).

Steps I have already tried and fail:

- Booting from an older kernel -> I get the same message, nothing happens
- Solution from this [link from Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390355/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000100-ubuntu-18) -> Nothing changes
- Accessing Gparted from a live USB, selecting check on the disk partition that has Ubuntu installed -> Again, nothing changes

I also have to declare that I cannot use an older kernel verson from GRUB and neither the recovery mode, as they both end up with the same error.

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208053/18-04-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempting-to-kill-init-exit-code-0x00000100

Comment: Hi Esther and thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have also consulted the aforementioned article and still end up with the same result.

Comment: did you turn off "fast startup" in Windows?

Comment: It was already turned off before any of this happened